# Android MediaRecorder Unlock API14+

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

What's the deal with unlocking a `Camera` before recording using `MediaRecorder`? The [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video) say:

> Video capture using the Android framework requires careful management of the Camera object and coordination with the MediaRecorder class. When recording video with Camera, you must manage the Camera.lock() and Camera.unlock() calls to allow MediaRecorder access to the camera hardware, in addition to the Camera.open() and Camera.release() calls.
>
> Note: Starting with Android 4.0 (API level 14), the Camera.lock() and Camera.unlock() calls are managed for you automatically.

However, no matter what device I test on, if I don't call `Camera.unlock` before `MediaRecorder.start` I get an exception `(start failed)`.

Are the docs lying, or am I doing something wrong?

My flow is to open the camera (using `Camera.open(int)`), set the recording hint to true, set the preview FPS and size, and display orientation. I then create the `MediaRecorder` and set the audio and video source, the output format, the frame rate, the size, the video bit rate, the audio and video encoder, the orientation hint, the output file, and then I call `MediaRecorder.prepare`.

If all that completes successfully, when the user clicks the "record" button, I call `MediaRecorder.start()` and an exception is thrown. If I instead call:

```
Camera.unlock();
MediaRecorder.start();
```

there is no exception.

Answer (score 0):

I have enough experience with MediaRecorder to say that this error can occur for a massive amount cases. 
by the way if trouble in lock/unlock methods the error would be

> unlock failed

In most cases the (start failed) error causes by wrong recorder initialization. 
Write your init method pls.

Comment: I don't want to write out the whole init method. However, the issue is that when `unlock` is not there it throws an exception. When it is there (and nothing else has changed) it works.

Comment: Mb it is stupid but camera is used by any kind of another process in yours app? That make sence: you unlock camera and then it free - yours recorder can in use))

Comment: There shouldn't be anything else using the camera, but I will check.

Comment: There is nothing else in the app using the camera.